# Retrive data in php sent from iOS

Tags: php, json

How can I retrive full name and emails in PHP? The format being received is specified as follows:

```
 array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["emails"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(17) "kate-bell@mac.com"
          [1]=>
          string(31) "www.creative-consulting-inc.com"
        }
        ["fullname"]=>
        string(9) "Kate Bell"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["emails"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(17) "d-higgins@mac.com"
        }
        ["fullname"]=>
        string(14) "Daniel Higgins"
      }
```

Edit: The Array can be of any length. Its just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access array with scopes

```
echo  $array['0']['emails']['0'];
echo  $array['0']['emails']['1'];
echo  $array['0']['fullname'];
```

This will output

```
kate-bell@mac.com
www.creative-consulting-inc.com
Kate Bell
```

Or you can loop with a foreach

```
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr['emails'] as $email_address)
    {
        echo $email_address;
    }
    echo $arr['fullname'];
}
```

This will give you all the result whithin the loop. First method instead will give you the oppurtunity to access each element only changing index

Answer (score 2):

A nested `foreach` will give you the emails and fullname:

```
foreach($array as $subArray)
{
    foreach($subArray['emails'] as $email)
    {
        echo $email;
    }
    echo $subArray['fullname'];
}
```